# Jetty returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, jetty

Hi I am porting my web app from tomcat to Jetty. I am using the Jetty runner to launch it.
I am using the following command to launch Jetty:

> java -jar jetty-runner.jar --port --path url-path path-to-war

However when I try to browse to the  from the browser I get the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 403
>
> Problem accessing . Reason:
>
> ```
> Forbidden
> ```

In the logs i see the following Warning:

> WARN:oejs.SecurityHandler:No authenticator for: {RoleInfo,C[*,
>   all_auth_users]}

I am trying to use Jetty out of the box and haven't customized any config anywhere. Is there any additional configuration required to make this work?

Comment: Which version of Jetty?

Comment: Likely cause: your war has security constraints defined, but you haven't specified what authentication type to use on the server side. look at `etc/jetty-testrealm.xml` for an example using the HashLoginService authenticator.

Comment: Yes, the web.xml indeed had a security-constraint defined, removing that has resolved the issue, thank you so much!

Comment: Copying my comment as a formal answer, so that this question can be flagged as answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Likely cause: your war/webapp has security constraints defined, but you haven't specified what authentication type to use on the server side.

Either:

- Remove your `<security-constraint>` in your war/webapp `WEB-INF/web.xml` file. or..
- Add an Authentication scheme on the server side.  Look at `etc/jetty-testrealm.xml` for an example using the HashLoginService authenticator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forget that paste the index.html example page. Its all.