# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Error accessing Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I am trying to run [this sample code](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/NativeAPIForIOS.zip) provided by IBM, but when I run it I get this error:
[image]

So I understand the HTTP 403, but where should I make neccesary changes to make this thing work? I saw this SO question: [Jetty returning 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142962/jetty-returning-403-forbidden) but no luck; I could not find that parameter anywhere in any file in my project.

Sometime earlier I got this error too **Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /**

Comment: What is your Worklight version... Also add to the question exact steps from creating the project to trying to access the console - full steps.

Comment: @IdanAdar Please see my update, I did not create new project. Downloaded the project, imported it and then tried to run it.

Comment: Are you certain your don't have Worklight 5.0.6 installed? Worklight 6.0 does not use Jetty as the underlying application server, yet in your screenshot it is Jetty that produces the error message; make sure you don't have any other services running on your machine that may be interfering.

Comment: Yes I double checked worklight 6.0 is the only version installed, but I have MAMP running but its on a different port.

Comment: Check for any running services; Try stopping MAMP anyway; sometimes a restart helps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lame, I had to deploy the adapter first then I deployed the native api, made neccessary changes voila I am good to go.